# How many even integers between $100$ and $1000$ have distinct digits?

Tags: combinatorics

How many even integers between $100$ and $1000$ have distinct digits?

I tried:

$9 \cdot 9 \cdot 5=405$

$9$ [$9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1$ ($9$)]

$9$ [$9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0$ ($10$)] - the first one picked ($1$)

$5$ ($0,2,4,6,8$)

But the answer of exercise is $328$. I don't know why.

Comment: Are you asking how many even numbers between $100$ and $1000$ have distinct digits?

Comment: They must be pair, so must end with pair number, like 0,2,4,6,8 I suppose

Comment: The word in English is "even"

Comment: @JMoravitz Word for what?

Comment: What you are apparently calling "pair numbers."  The set of numbers $\{\dots,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,\dots\}=2\Bbb Z = \{2k~:~k\in\Bbb Z\}$ is referred to as the set of *even* numbers.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.